# PHAsset image comes pixelated while showing it in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, phasset

I have this code which I am using in collectionView to get the image.

```
           // Code in CollectionView's cellForItemAtIndex

           // Image

                PHImageManager.defaultManager().getPhoto(asset, size: cell.thumbnail.frame.size) { (image) in

                    if let properImage = image
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            cell.thumbnail.image = properImage
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.thumbnail.image  = UIImage()
                    }
                }
```

And the `getPhoto` method.

```
//MARK: PHImageManager

extension PHImageManager
{
    func getPhoto( asset : PHAsset, size : CGSize, completion : (image : UIImage?) -> ())
    {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.networkAccessAllowed = true
        options.synchronous = false
        options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat

        _ = self.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {

            result , _ in

            if let resultValue  = result as UIImage?
            {
                completion(image: resultValue)
            }
            else
            {
                completion(image: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Whenever I load images into collectionView, I can see that the visible cell's images are pixelated. When I scroll thorough the images it appeared properly with high quality image.

Also I have tried all combinations of `resizeMode` and `deliveryMode`, didn't help me. I have tried by enabling `synchronous` too.

I want to show `hight quality images in the first time` itself. I don't want to scroll through the `collectionView` to get it.

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale your image size depending on the scale of your screen like this:

`let retinaMultiplier = UIScreen.main.scale
let size = CGSize(width:self.bounds.size.width * retinaMultiplier, height:    self.bounds.size.height * retinaMultiplier)`

and pass this size into `targetSize` of your `requestImageForAsset` method.

And be sure you chose the right options for assets fetching.